# Coalesce and Concat in the same statement, Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, concatenation, coalesce

I am trying to concat an individual's first and last name together but coalesce a team name when there is a null value. Unfortunately my syntax is returning a SPACE, so coalesce does not recognize it as a null value.. What can I do to correct this?

Syntax I am currently using:

```
coalesce((Concat(first_name,' ',last_name)),team_name)
```

Comment: So you want to get `team_name` even if only one of the other names is `null`?

Answer (score 6):

Just use the concatenation operator, `||`:

```
coalesce(first_name || ' ' || last_name, team_name)
```

The `concat()` function ignores `NULL` values.  The operator returns `NULL`.