# Concat function in a coalesce

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to concat two fields in a materialised view. In the concat I also use a concat function. It looks like this.

```
   coalesce(
     concat(table1.city, '/' ,  REPLACE(table1.name,' ', '-')),
     concat(table2.city, '/' ,  REPLACE(table2.name,' ', '-'))
   ) as slug,
```

However this will always return the first item in the `coalesce` function since the slash '/' always returns true.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Use `||` instead - that will yield `null` if any of the involved expressions is `null`

Comment: Thanks. I found the answer also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41770098/coalesce-and-concat-in-the-same-statement-postgres.